# Cannot run apps with Vulkan

Tags: intel, arch-linux

I'm on Arch Linux and after last update (I guess this related with new version of mesa when they remove old drivers) I cannot run apps with vulkan. I got next outputs when run `vkcube` command and UI сloses immediately:

```
Selected GPU 0: Intel(R) Xe Graphics (TGL GT2), type: IntegratedGpu
vulkan: No DRI3 support detected - required for presentation
Note: you can probably enable DRI3 in your Xorg config
Could not find both graphics and present queues
```

lspci | grep -iE "3d|vga|video":

```
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
```

cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf:

```
Section "Module"
  Load          "glx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "modesetting"
    Option      "AccelMethod"           "glamor"
    Option      "DRI"                   "3"
    Option      "Backlight"             "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

Xorg.0.log:
https://pastebin.com/xfwZ1ii2

Please, help me to fix that

UPD: I replace my xorg config on this and now vulkan is work fine.

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "DRI"    "3"
EndSection
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "DRI"    "3"
EndSection
EOF
```