# Vulkan: no DRI3 support detected on VNC server (Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, vnc

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 4 on the latest version Debian Bookworm 64-bits, and need to use vulkan in a VNC session. It works when wired to a screen: `vkcube` opens a window with a 3D rotating cube. However, it fails when the same command is used in a VNC session: `vkcube` returns "vulkan: no DRI3 support detected...".
The VNC session is started with *TightVNC*.

I checked the output of `vulkaninfo`  in both cases, and the only difference is that, when wired to a screen, two GPUs appear in the *Presentable Surfaces* section, instead of one when the command is used in the VNC session. The additional gpu is defined as follows:

```
GPU id : 0 (V3D 4.2.14):
    Surface types: count = 2
        VK_KHR_xcb_surface
        VK_KHR_xlib_surface
    Formats: count = 2
        SurfaceFormat[0]:
            format = FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_SRGB
            colorSpace = COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR
        SurfaceFormat[1]:
            format = FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
            colorSpace = COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR
    Present Modes: count = 4
        PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR
        PRESENT_MODE_MAILBOX_KHR
        PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR
        PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_RELAXED_KHR
    VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR:
    -------------------------
        minImageCount = 3
        maxImageCount = 0
        currentExtent:
            width  = 256
            height = 256
        minImageExtent:
            width  = 256
            height = 256
        maxImageExtent:
            width  = 256
            height = 256
        maxImageArrayLayers = 1
        supportedTransforms: count = 1
            SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR
        currentTransform = SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR
        supportedCompositeAlpha: count = 2
            COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR
            COMPOSITE_ALPHA_INHERIT_BIT_KHR
        supportedUsageFlags: count = 6
            IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT
            IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT
            IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT
            IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT
            IMAGE_USAGE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_BIT
            IMAGE_USAGE_ATTACHMENT_FEEDBACK_LOOP_BIT_EXT
    VkSurfaceCapabilities2EXT:
    --------------------------
        supportedSurfaceCounters:
            None
    VkSurfacePresentModeCompatibilityEXT:
    -------------------------------------
        presentModeCount = 1
        pPresentModes: count = 1

    VkSurfacePresentScalingCapabilitiesEXT:
    ---------------------------------------
        supportedPresentScaling:
            None
        supportedPresentGravityX:
            None
        supportedPresentGravityY:
            None
        minScaledImageExtent:
            width  = 256
            height = 256
        maxScaledImageExtent:
            width  = 256
            height = 256

    VkSurfaceProtectedCapabilitiesKHR:
    ----------------------------------
        supportsProtected = false
```

I guess I have to point to this additional GPU when opening the VNC server but did not find how to do it.

Currently, the VNC server is started with `systemctl` and the following .service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Open a virtual session on boot with user "capteur"
After=multi-user.target

[Service]

Type=forking
User=capteur
ExecStartPre=sleep 20
ExecStart=vncserver

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The xstartup script is the default one:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb "$HOME/.Xresources"
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

Finally, I saw on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1725797/cannot-run-apps-with-vulkan) that the issue might come from */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d*, but couldn't find a way to fix it myself. So here is the only file in my */etc/X11/xorg.conf.d* directory (again the default one):

```
Section "OutputClass"
  Identifier "vc4"
  MatchDriver "vc4"
  Driver "modesetting"
  Option "PrimaryGPU" "true"
EndSection
```

I also noticed two files *vncserver-virtual-vnc.conf* and *vncserver-virtual-dummy.conf* sitting in */etc/X11/* so maybe they should be edited too.

Is there a way to enable DRI3 inside a VNC session, and if yes, what am I missing ?

I hope someone can help me with this,
Bye !

*NB: Since I don't know if it's more a Raspberry Pi or a Linux question, I made the exact same post on forum.Raspberrypi. I'll update this post if the issue is solved there and vice versa*

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I encounter this issue only if I use the latest versions of debian bookworm (releases of 2024_03_13 and later). Reverting to the release of 2023_12_05 fixed it.
It can be found [there](https://downloads.raspberrypi.com/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2023-12-06/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).